# how to work with winsock using https in vb6.0

Tags: vba, vb6

how to use get and post request using winsock for https. It works ok with http.but when i am using https  i am getting this response..

Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.
Reason: You're speaking plain HTTP to an SSL-enabled server port.
 Instead use the HTTPS scheme to access this URL, please.

Comment: If you are using a basic Socket you will need to implement the entirety of SSL/TLS which unlikely to be practical.  Use an HTTP client (XMLHTTP/WinInet/Internet Transfer Control) instead.

Comment: how we can implement ssl/tls any idea...

Comment: With great difficulty using VB6, you would be better of using an existing HTTP Client.

Comment: how we can use winInet.dll with get and post in vb6.0.

Comment: [MSDN SAMPLE: Vbhttp.exe Demonstrates How to Use HTTP WinInet APIs in Visual Basic](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/259100) but `MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP` would be much simpler (COM)

Answer (score 0):

using help from msdn[wininet](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/259100%60). sending file and parameter.

```
    Private Sub btSend_Click()

    Dim iRetVal              As Integer

    Dim sbuffer              As String * 1024

    Dim lBufferLen           As Long

    Dim sStatus              As String

    Dim postVariable         As String

    Dim LengthOFPostVariable As Long

    Dim SecFlag              As Long

    Dim dwSecFlag            As Long

    Dim dwPort               As Long

    Screen.MousePointer = vbHourglass
    btSend.Enabled = True
    lBufferLen = Len(sbuffer)

    If CBool(hInternetSession) Then
       SetStatus "InternetQueryOption"
       InternetQueryOption hInternetSession, INTERNET_OPTION_VERSION, vDllVersion, Len(vDllVersion)
       lblMajor = vDllVersion.lMajorVersion
       lblMinor = vDllVersion.lMinorVersion
       SetStatus "InternetConnect"

       If checkSecure.Value = 1 Then
           Debug.Print "Establishing secure connection" & " "
           dwPort = INTERNET_DEFAULT_HTTPS_PORT
           Debug.Print "Setting security flags" & " "
           SecFlag = INTERNET_FLAG_SECURE Or INTERNET_FLAG_IGNORE_CERT_CN_INVALID Or INTERNET_FLAG_IGNORE_CERT_DATE_INVALID
       Else
           dwPort = INTERNET_DEFAULT_HTTP_PORT
           SecFlag = 0
       End If

       hInternetConnect = InternetConnect(hInternetSession, CheckUrl, dwPort, txtUsername.Text, txtPassword.Text, INTERNET_SERVICE_HTTP, 0, 0)

       If hInternetConnect > 0 Then

           SetStatus "HttpOpenRequest"

           If optGet.Value = True Then
               postVariable = vbNullString
               LengthOFPostVariable = 0
               hHttpOpenRequest = HttpOpenRequest(hInternetConnect, "GET", GetUrlObject, "HTTP/1.0", vbNullString, 0, INTERNET_FLAG_RELOAD Or INTERNET_FLAG_KEEP_CONNECTION Or SecFlag, 0)
           Else
               hHttpOpenRequest = HttpOpenRequest(hInternetConnect, "POST", GetUrlObject, "HTTP/1.0", vbNullString, 0, INTERNET_FLAG_RELOAD Or SecFlag, 0)
           End If

           If CBool(hHttpOpenRequest) Then
               SetStatus "HttpSendRequest"

               Dim strPostData As String, strBoundary As String, strHttp As String, strbody As String

               strBoundary = "3fbd04f5-b1ed-4060-99b9-fca7ff59c113"

               Dim sHeader As String

               sHeader = "Content-Type: multipart/form-data, boundary=" & strBoundary & vbCrLf
               iRetVal = HttpAddRequestHeaders(hHttpOpenRequest, sHeader, Len(sHeader), HTTP_ADDREQ_FLAG_REPLACE Or HTTP_ADDREQ_FLAG_ADD)

               Dim dwTimeOut As Long, lngLength As Long

               strPostData = GetFileContents("c:\1.pdf")

               strbody = "--" & strBoundary & vbCrLf
               strbody = strbody & "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=""id""" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "1" & vbCrLf

               strbody = strbody & "--" & strBoundary & vbCrLf
               strbody = strbody & "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=""name""" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "ABCD" & vbCrLf

               strbody = strbody & "--" & strBoundary & vbCrLf
               strbody = strbody & "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=""age""" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "26" & vbCrLf

               strbody = strbody & "--" & strBoundary & vbCrLf
               strbody = strbody & "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=""height""" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "155" & vbCrLf

               strbody = strbody & "--" & strBoundary & vbCrLf
               strbody = strbody & "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=""weight""" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "56" & vbCrLf

               strbody = strbody & "--" & strBoundary & vbCrLf
               strbody = strbody & "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=""" & "file" & """; filename=""" & "1.pdf" & """" & vbCrLf
               strbody = strbody & "Content-Type: application/octet-stream" & vbCrLf
               strbody = strbody & vbCrLf & strPostData
               strbody = strbody & vbCrLf & "--" & strBoundary & vbCrLf & "--"


               lngLength = Len(strbody)

               dwTimeOut = 420000 ' time out is set to 7 minutes
               iRetVal = InternetSetOption(hHttpOpenRequest, INTERNET_OPTION_CONNECT_TIMEOUT, dwTimeOut, 4)

               iRetVal = InternetSetOption(hHttpOpenRequest, INTERNET_OPTION_RECEIVE_TIMEOUT, dwTimeOut, 4)

               iRetVal = InternetSetOption(hHttpOpenRequest, INTERNET_OPTION_SEND_TIMEOUT, dwTimeOut, 4)

          Resend:
               iRetVal = HttpSendRequest(hHttpOpenRequest, vbNullString, 0, strbody, lngLength)

               If (iRetVal <> 1) And (Err.LastDllError = 12045) Then
                   MsgBox "Invalid CA"
                   'Certificate Authority is invalid.
                   Debug.Print "Invalid Cert Auth, resending" & " "
                   dwSecFlag = SECURITY_FLAG_IGNORE_UNKNOWN_CA
                   iRetVal = InternetSetOption(hHttpOpenRequest, INTERNET_OPTION_SECURITY_FLAGS, dwSecFlag, 4)
                   Debug.Print iRetVal & " " & Err.LastDllError & " " & "INTERNET_OPTION_SECURITY_FLAGS"
                   GoTo Resend
               End If

               If iRetVal Then

                   Dim dwStatus As Long, dwStatusSize As Long

                   dwStatusSize = Len(dwStatus)
                   HttpQueryInfo hHttpOpenRequest, HTTP_QUERY_FLAG_NUMBER Or HTTP_QUERY_STATUS_CODE, dwStatus, dwStatusSize, 0

                   Select Case dwStatus

                       Case HTTP_STATUS_PROXY_AUTH_REQ
                           iRetVal = InternetSetOptionStr(hHttpOpenRequest, INTERNET_OPTION_PROXY_USERNAME, "IUSR_WEIHUA1", Len("IUSR_WEIHUA1") + 1)
                           iRetVal = InternetSetOptionStr(hHttpOpenRequest, INTERNET_OPTION_PROXY_PASSWORD, "IUSR_WEIHUA1", Len("IUSR_WEIHUA1") + 1)
                           GoTo Resend

                       Case HTTP_STATUS_DENIED
                           iRetVal = InternetSetOptionStr(hHttpOpenRequest, INTERNET_OPTION_USERNAME, "IUSR_WEIHUA1", Len("IUSR_WEIHUA1") + 1)
                           iRetVal = InternetSetOptionStr(hHttpOpenRequest, INTERNET_OPTION_PASSWORD, "IUSR_WEIHUA1", Len("IUSR_WEIHUA1") + 1)
                           GoTo Resend
                   End Select

                   SetStatus "HttpQueryInfo"
                   'response headers
                   GetQueryInfo hHttpOpenRequest, lblContentType, HTTP_QUERY_CONTENT_TYPE
                   GetQueryInfo hHttpOpenRequest, lblContentLength, HTTP_QUERY_CONTENT_LENGTH
                   GetQueryInfo hHttpOpenRequest, lblLastModified, HTTP_QUERY_LAST_MODIFIED
                   GetQueryInfo hHttpOpenRequest, lblVersion, HTTP_QUERY_VERSION
                   GetQueryInfo hHttpOpenRequest, lblStatusCode, HTTP_QUERY_STATUS_CODE
                   GetQueryInfo hHttpOpenRequest, lblStatusText, HTTP_QUERY_STATUS_TEXT
                   GetQueryInfo hHttpOpenRequest, lblRawHeaders, HTTP_QUERY_RAW_HEADERS
                   GetQueryInfo hHttpOpenRequest, txtResponseHeaders, HTTP_QUERY_RAW_HEADERS_CRLF
                   GetQueryInfo hHttpOpenRequest, lblForwarded, HTTP_QUERY_FORWARDED
                   GetQueryInfo hHttpOpenRequest, lblServer, HTTP_QUERY_SERVER
                   GetQueryInfo hHttpOpenRequest, lblRequestMethod, HTTP_QUERY_REQUEST_METHOD
                   GetQueryInfo hHttpOpenRequest, lblPragma, HTTP_QUERY_FLAG_REQUEST_HEADERS + HTTP_QUERY_PRAGMA
                   GetQueryInfo hHttpOpenRequest, txtRequestHeaders, HTTP_QUERY_FLAG_REQUEST_HEADERS + HTTP_QUERY_RAW_HEADERS_CRLF
                   GetQueryInfo hHttpOpenRequest, lblUserAgent, HTTP_QUERY_FLAG_REQUEST_HEADERS + HTTP_QUERY_USER_AGENT
                   GetQueryInfo hHttpOpenRequest, lblRequestMethod2, HTTP_QUERY_FLAG_REQUEST_HEADERS + HTTP_QUERY_REQUEST_METHOD
                   sStatus = "Ready"
                   btSend.Enabled = False
                   btGet.Enabled = True
               Else
                   ' HttpSendRequest failed
                   sStatus = "HttpSendRequest call failed; Error code: " & Err.LastDllError & "."
               End If

           Else
               ' HttpOpenRequest failed
                  sStatus = "HttpOpenRequest call failed; Error code: " & Err.LastDllError & "."
           End If

           Else
               ' InternetConnect failed
               sStatus = "InternetConnect call failed; Error code: " &    Err.LastDllError & "."
       End If

      Else
           ' hInternetSession handle not allocated
       sStatus = "InternetOpen call failed: Error code: " & Err.LastDllError & "."
     End If

        SetStatus sStatus

     If optPost.Value Then
         GetServerFileContent
      End If

      Screen.MousePointer = vbDefault
    End `




     Public Sub GetServerFileContent()

     Dim bdoLoop            As Boolean

     Dim sReadBuffer        As String * 2048

     Dim lNumberOfBytesRead As Long

     Dim sbuffer            As String


     SetStatus "InternetReadFile"
     bdoLoop = True

     While bdoLoop

       sReadBuffer = vbNullString
       bdoLoop = InternetReadFile(hHttpOpenRequest, sReadBuffer, Len(sReadBuffer), lNumberOfBytesRead)
       sbuffer = sbuffer & Left$(sReadBuffer, lNumberOfBytesRead)

       If Not CBool(lNumberOfBytesRead) Then bdoLoop = False

       Wend


     Debug.Print sbuffer

   End Sub
```